# Issue starting method from other class

Tags: c#, class, methods, call

i am trying to do something that should be quite simple, call a method from a another class, I have allready done it once in my project but this time it doesn't work.

How I am calling the method:

```
Characters.Character_One.MoveLeft();
```

this is the contents of the method I am trying to call:

```
public static void MoveLeft(Character_One c)
{
    c.s.Top -= movespeed;
}
```

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff, I suggest you dive into a book first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing it the parameter it requires - an instance of `Character_One`.

```
var charOne = new Character_One();

Characters.Character_One.MoveLeft(charOne);
```